# How to store 2 chars in one byte in MIPS?

Tags: mips

My question is, it is possible to store 2 chars in one byte in mips?

If yes, how can i do that? I've already searched alot in the internet and i cannot find how to do that, i also tryied to copy to an empty array of strings, but it doesnt work.

```
.data
string: .asciiz "ola"
string2: .asciiz ""

a: .ascii "a"
a1: .ascii "b"

e: .ascii "e"
e1: .ascii "f"

i: .ascii "i"
i1: .ascii "j"

o: .ascii "o"
o1: .ascii "p"

u: .ascii "u"
u1: .ascii "v"

tam: .word 3

.text 

main:
lw $t6, tam #string length
lb $t1, string($t0) #read bit by bit

la $a0, string
la $a1, string2

lb $s0, a #save in register the char that we want to search
lb $s1, a1 #save in register the char that we want to replace


beq $t0, $t6, done

beq $t1, $s0, continua #if the char of (bit by bit) its like the char of             chars, swap it
bne $t1, $s0, else #if not, saves
else:
lb $s0, e
lbu $s1, e1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, else2

else2:  
lb $s0, i
lb $s1, i1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, else3

else3:  
lb $s0, o
lb $s1, o1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, else4                         

else4: 
lb $s0, u
lb $s1, u1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, store

continua:
move $v0, $a0

sb $s1, string($t0) #do the swap 
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #+1 in the index
j main 

store:

move $v0, $a0

sb $t1, string($t0) #saves
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #+1 in the index
j main
done:
move $a1, $v0
la $a0, string
li $v0, 4
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Kind regards.

Comment: you want to store 16 bits in 8 bits?

Comment: Zip them.  Only works for large values of 2.  More seriously, 4 bits can store 16 distinct values.  A - Z requires 26 distinct values.  You *can* store 2 *digit* characters.

Comment: @old_timer something like that.

Comment: Is this for homework?  Edit your question to include the exact wording of the assignment.  As written your problem is not solvable.

Comment: How do you plan to do that, it is like putting both feet in one cowboy boot that exactly fits one.

Comment: it takes 16 bits to store 16 bits...can store 16 in 32 but not in 15, not in 8 not in 3, am I missing something here?

Comment: If you're working on an environment with _very_ limited memory, the usual trick is to make a custom char table where most graphical entries consist of 2 letters commonly seen one next to the other in the language you're building your software for.